# PHP using a variable in a mysql query with magic_quotes

Tags: php, mysql, security, magic-quotes

I have a mysql query that uses a value in an array as part of the WHERE statement. How am I supposed to include this variable?

Here is the sql:
`"AND gender = '{$user_array[\"gender\"]}'"`

PHP returns this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting T_STRING`

I have `magic_quotes` turned on. I've seen some posts suggesting setting the array's value to another variable, but seems unnecessary if I have magic quotes. Is this correct?

Comment: first thing you should do is turn off the magic quotes: they've been removed from PHP 5.4.x. Then read up on PDO (or mysqli), then consider that, when using double quotes, everything between the curly braces is considered _"not quoted"_, and you normally wouldn't escape the quotes when using an associative array: `$user_array['gender']` can (and should) be placed in between those braces as is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"AND gender = '{$user_array['gender']}'"
```

It was the backslashes that were killing it.

Or you can even do:

```
"AND gender = '$user_array[gender]'"
```

Or:

```
"AND gender = '" . $user_array['gender'] ."'"
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/lrJllI1K

But all of this put together, you should be using **prepared queries**

Comment: @DonnyP [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Thanks Neal - unfortunately working on a codebase that still using mysql_query

Comment: @DonnyP well there is never a better time than now to switch over to a new way of doing things ^_^ Here is a good reference site: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Haha true, we'll need to switch the entire base at once, it will be strange if some code is using my PDO and the rest is still in mysql

Comment: Using the second option gives this `Notice: Use of undefined constant gender - assumed 'gender'`

Comment: @DonnyP I never said that it wouldn't throw a notice :-P

Comment: I have no idea, I think someone came through and downvoted every comment?

Comment: @DonnyP this is a comment. My answer is an **answer** :-P

Answer (score 0):

Just put the entire query in `double quotes` and then do like `AND gender = '$user_array['gender']'`

Comment: Sorry, but that's just wrong: there's ambiguity in that statement: do you want the string value of `$user_array`, followed by the regular string `['gender']` (giving something along the lines of `(array)['gender']`), or do you want the string value of `$user_value['gender']`? no way to know, hence the curly braces are a necessity

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can do a string concat in PHP and keep your SQL in double quotes which may solve your issue:

```
"AND gender = '" . $user_array['gender'] . "'...
```